# How to get width from animated div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thanks in advance for your support here. I have a simple code here but I wonder why it doesn't work.

This code below was put into a variable "percent"

```
var percent = $('#div').animate({width:80 + '%'},1000);
```

and I want to use the variable to become a text or content to a specific div. I tried to do it this way, however it doesn't work.

```
$('#val').text(percent); or $('#val').html(percent);
```

I tried to use the parseInt() function from JavaScript, but it doesn't work as well.

```
$('#web-design').text(parseInt(percent));
```

Do you have any suggestions or is this possible?

Comment: with your code `percent` will return a jQuery object. Since there is nothing `variable` about your code you can hard-code 80?

Comment: thanks, yes! it returns to Object. All I wanted is while the value from 0% - 80% will display into the specific div. is this possible? or is there anyway to extract it from the "percent"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is going to animate to `80%` width in 1 second (1000 ms).  You can increase the percentage width by 1% each iteration and update your `#val` at the same time until you hit 80.  Below is the example based on 10000ms (10 secs), you can change the starting parameters such as `duration, endWidth, startWidth` to suit.
Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zthaucda/

HTML:

```
<div class="my-anim-div"></div>
<button class="start-animating">Start animation</button>
<div id="val">Width will display here</div>
```

CSS:

```
.my-anim-div {
    width:0%;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Javascript including jQuery library:

```
var duration = 10000;
var endWidth = 80;
var startWidth = 0;
$('.start-animating').on('click', function () {
    // work out the interval to make the animation in `duration`
    var interval = duration / (endWidth - startWidth);
    console.log(interval);
    var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        // Increment the startWidth and update the width of the div and the display
        startWidth++
        // update div width
        $('.my-anim-div').animate({
            'width': startWidth + '%'
        }, interval);
        // update display
        $('#val').text(startWidth + '%');
        if (startWidth == 80) {
            // then exit the interval
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
    }, interval);
});
```

Comment: thanks Rob, this looks great, but is there any way that it will automatically load up instead of using onclick?

Comment: @user1256346 Yes, just remove the listener around it and place it on an `ready` e.g. `$(document).ready(function(){... rest of code`

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the line code it is correct

```
var percent = $('#div').animate({width:80 + '%'},1000);
```

To find the with property for #div I will do something like this

```
$('#val').text($("#div").css("width"))
```

or

```
$('#val').text($("#div").width())
```

Comment: thanks, but value returns to 30px. is it possible that while the value animating from 0%-80% will display into the specific div?

Answer (score 1):

The `animate` function does not return the changes to the element. To get the width you will have to use `.width()` but you will get it in pixel and not percentage.

```
var width = $('#div').width();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
 $('#div1').animate({width:80 + '%'},{
 duration:1000,
 easing:'swing',
 step: function() { // called on every step
        $('#div1').text(Math.ceil($('#div1').width()/$('#div1').parent().width()*100) + "%");
    }
 });
```

This will print the Div-Width % as text in Div at every step of update.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to get the current width of the div you can use clientWidth property:

```
$('#div')[0].clientWidth
```